# Replace function removing Ones / 1 when removing char(185) (superscript 1)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, collation, temporary-tables, unicode

Ok as the title suggests this is occuring.

When using the `REPLACE` function on char(185) for data in a temporary table, ones ("1") are being removed as well.

SQL SERVER 2008R2
UNICODE Data

DB collation - collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
Tempdb has default

Any other details I could provide which might be helpful, let me know.

Comment: Please read [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and edit your question to add the additional detail.

Comment: Yeah youre right I forgot the collation as well. which turned out to be the problem. thanks though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CHAR(185)`, being VARCHAR data and using an 8-bit code page, can be a different character depending on the code page being used (which is determined by the collation of the current database when using the `CHAR()` function). In many code pages, including the common Windows-1252 (Latin1_General), the character is a superscript 1 (i.e. "**<sup>1</sup>**" ). This character, depending on the collation / code page being used, might have a "best fit" mapping to a regular "1".

Also, when using a Windows collation, case-sensitivity can affect the outcome of matches between subscript, superscript, and regular versions of the same characters (seriously! see example below). This also covers `NVARCHAR` / Unicode data (including UTF-8 in `VARCHAR` starting in SQL Server 2019).

**When needing to match on specific characters you need to use a *binary* collation (i.e. one ending in `_BIN2` unless on SQL Server 2005 or older, in which case only the `_BIN` collations are available).**

```sql
SELECT CHAR(185)
WHERE  CHAR(185) = '1' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
-- no rows (SQL Server collation, code page 1252, case insensitive)



SELECT CHAR(185)
WHERE  CHAR(185) = '1' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP437_CI_AS
-- 1 row (SQL Server collation, code page 437, case insensitive)

SELECT CHAR(185)
WHERE  CHAR(185) = '1' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP437_CS_AS
-- 1 row (SQL Server collation, code page 437, case sensitive)



SELECT CHAR(185)
WHERE  CHAR(185) = '1' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS
-- 1 row (Windows collation, code page 1252, case insensitive)

SELECT CHAR(185)
WHERE  CHAR(185) = '1' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CS_AS
-- no rows (Windows collation, code page 1252, case sensitive)



SELECT CHAR(185)
WHERE  CHAR(185) = '1' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2;
-- no rows (Windows collation, code page 1252, _BIN2 collation; always works!)
```

As noted above, Unicode data (regardless of type of collation) works the same as `VARCHAR` data used with a Windows collation (because both scenarios use the same Unicode rules):

```sql
SELECT NCHAR(185)
WHERE  NCHAR(185) = N'1' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS
-- 1 row (Windows collation, Unicode data, case insensitive)

SELECT NCHAR(185)
WHERE  NCHAR(185) = N'1' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CS_AS
-- no rows (Windows collation, Unicode data, case sensitive)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone wants to know - the issue was collation. When I wrote the question I didn't realize the #temp table I was using had a different collation than the default for the database I was working within. It was a simple solution and honestly something I shouldve thought of long before coming here with questions.

Comment: Hi Doug. Please add some details to this question. Like the two collations being used (current DB and `tempdb`), and specifically how you fixed it (e.g. did you specify the collation when creating the temp table? did you specify the `COLLATE` clause in the query? did you use `DATABASE_DEFAULT` or did you use a specific collation?, etc). Thanks. Also, please see [my answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/250674/30859) for a full explanation of what was happening and another option to fix, which might apply to more situations than just this one :-).

Comment: @solomonRutzky i solved the issue by collating the info into the temp table.

Comment: Thanks. If you don't mind, can you please edit this answer to add some detail for others having this problem who might find this question and need some guidance? What you've said so far, even "collating the info into the temp table" isn't going to help most people, I don't think. Not asking for a lot, just a sentence or two with specifics, such as: "Added `COLLATE DATEBASE_DEFAULT` to the column in the `CREATE TABLE` statement" or "Added `COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CS_AS` to the column in the `SELECT ... INTO #TempTable` statement, else it used `tempdb`'s collation: `Latin1_General_CI_AS`".

Comment: @SolomonRutzky I def will when I have a minute - i had planned to just havent been able to do so (on a different  network here and have to wait till i get home to to access the sql script i have saved).

Comment: Doug, ok, sounds good...thanks!